# use parameters in window.location.replace

Tags: javascript, php, url-parameters, window.location

I have the following script which works fine:

```
if(error1 == 1){
    window.alert('You have already signed up!');
    window.location.replace('index.php');
    }
```

But when I want to use the following URL instead of index.php, it does not substitute the parameters:

```
if(error1 == 1){
    window.alert('You have already signed up!');
    window.location.replace('http://polimovie.deib.polimi.it/Version3/index.php?campaign=".$Campaign_id."&worker=".$Worker_id."');
    }
```

This code, redirects me to `http://polimovie.deib.polimi.it/Version3/index.php?campaign=.$Campaign_id.&worker=.$Worker_id.` while I need the parameters be replaced with their actual numbers.

I know I can use php header, I also used it within my php codes like this and with both it workerd fine:

```
echo "<script>alert('PLEASE SIGN UP FIRST!');window.location = 'http://polimovie.deib.polimi.it/Version3/index.php?campaign=".$Campaign_id."&worker=".$Worker_id."';</script>";
```

but I would like to know how I can use parameters with window.location.replace.

Thanks,

Comment: is the JS inside of a PHP file which has those variables declared and filled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try as below :

```
if(error1 == 1){
    window.alert('You have already signed up!');
    window.location.replace('http://polimovie.deib.polimi.it/Version3/index.php?campaign=<?php echo $Campaign_id; ?>&worker=<?php echo $Worker_id; ?>');
    }
```

**Above will work if this is a php file and not js file**

Comment: delete the dots before you `echo`

Comment: Also, you should not need `"` around you get vars. since they're devided by `&*=`

Comment: Actually, its inside javascript part. but the file is saved as php because it contains also php.

Comment: @mOna That's fine, as long as the variables you're adding here ( `$Campaign_id` and `$Worker_id` ) are declared above these lines of code. you're fine

Comment: Yes @mOna you can use like that.

Answer (score 3):

@Mona:
In the code given below i have used produt_id as the javascript variable.

```
var product_id=1;
window.location.replace("/newpage/page.php?id=" + product_id);
```

So, if you will compare this with your code you are required to take the values of your php variable in the javascript variable and then you have to pass them according to the above method which i have given in the example.

Hope this will make your day!

Cheers :) :P